# Automate Interactive session using script

Tags: bash, matlab, csh, cadence

I need to run interactive software in parallel to an another software.

This interactive software (Cadence) runs on a separate terminal.

Using Matlab, I want to invoke a csh script that gives certain commands to this interactive session, which is running in parallel.

Basically, I am performing some computations using Matlab and the results of which are simulated from using this interactive software (Cadence).

I am aware of the Matlab command 'system' that can be used to invoke a script.

How, can I do it?
Also, if there is any alternate/shortcut method, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.
Aksh

Comment: Does Cadence have any ways to send commands to it? If not, you can use something like AutohotKey on Windows or xdotool on Linux to "fake" mouse clicks.

Comment: I am not using the graphical interface to it, rather I am using its interactive command line session.

Comment: Also, I need to send commands to this live interactive command-line via another script.

Comment: I think that you might be looking for `expect`? https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index – there are some other similar tools are well (I think I saw a Python version somewhere once).